# DocumentDb SELECT for array property doesn't return anything

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Here's what my document in DocumentDb looks like:

```
{
   "id": 123,
   "favoriteTeams": [
      {
         "id": 234,
         "name": "Boston Celtics"
      },
      {
         "id": 345,
         "name": "Boston Red Sox"
      },
      {
         "id": 456,
         "name": "New England Patriots"
      }
   ]
}
```

If I run the following SELECT statement through the portal, I get the following results:

```
SELECT c.favoriteTeams FROM Collection c WHERE c.id = 123
```

And the result looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "favoriteTeams": [
          {
            "id": 234,
            "name": "Boston Celtics"
          },
          {
            "id": 345,
            "name": "Boston Red Sox"
          },
          {
            "id": 456,
            "name": "New England Patriots"
          }
      ]
   }
]
```

Two issues:

1. If I send the same exact query through my code in my ASP.NET app, I get a single object with all null values in it.
2. As you can see in the results, it's creating an object inside the array it returns. How can I get only the teams in an array. In other words, I don't want the "favoriteTeams" object in the result. I'm thinking this may be causing the issue in my code where I'm not able to bind the result to my objects because my code is expecting an array -- NOT an object that contains the array.

I'm not sure if getting an array will solve the first issue but I want to at least try it. I also want to learn how to get an array with the teams in it -- without the "favoriteTeams" object in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your query and add the `VALUE` keyword, you'll just get the array:

```
SELECT VALUE c.favoriteTeams FROM Collection c WHERE c.id = "123"
```

Results:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 234,
      "name": "Boston Celtics"
    },
    {
      "id": 345,
      "name": "Boston Red Sox"
    },
    {
      "id": 456,
      "name": "New England Patriots"
    }
  ]
]
```